# How to get selected name element of kendo MVVM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mvvm, kendo-ui

How to get selected name element of kendo MVVM
HTML:

```
    <select  data-role="multiselect"
                       data-placeholder="Select..."
                       data-text-field="name"
                       data-value-field="name"
                       data-bind="value: sel,
                                  source: list"
                                  ></select>
<label> Selected:</label><span data-bind="text: sel"> </span>
```

What should I do in the JS to get value of selected element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for **multiselect** is an array so when shown to span, it will show [object object]. You can bind the displayed value to another property and join the array using the `change` event.

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mr37o016/) for a quick demo.